# Can I take chocolate to Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

Australia is well known for having very strict rules on what food and plant-based materials can be brought into the country, to try to keep the country free of diseases. Some food/animal/plant things can never be brought into the country, some may be if suitably declared, and a very small number are always fine.

What's the situation with chocolates though? I'd quite like to take a nice box of chocolates with me as a gift for someone when I go to Australia, but only if I'll be allowed to take them in. Does anyone know what the rules are for chocolates? Are they a never / usually ok if declared / normally fine thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chocolate (and biscuits/cookies) are OK!

A travel blogger [actually emailed the Australian Customs](http://austour.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/australian-customs-biscuits-and-chocolate-are-ok/) to see what the case was, and got a response:

> Thank you for your enquiry about bringing biscuits and chocolates into > Australia as part of your personal luggage.
>
> Cooked cakes, including cakes containing custard or dairy based fillings that have been cooked with the cake (excluding cheesecakes,
>   mooncakes, dairy puddings, vanilla slices or Dulce de Leche), bread
>   and shelf stable biscuits are allowed into Australia as part of your
>   personal baggage from any country provided the items do not require
>   refrigeration to maintain quality. Items that do not meet these import
>   conditions must be re-exported from Australia or destroyed. Re-export
>   of the items must be paid for by the importer.
>
> Cakes decorated with material such as fresh flowers, leaves, fruits or raw nuts that were not cooked with the cake may need to have
>   the flowers, leaves, fruits or nuts removed. Alternatively, cakes
>   decorated with prohibited fresh flowers, leaves, fruits or raw nuts
>   that were not cooked with the cake must be re-exported or destroyed.
>   Re-export must be paid for by the importer.
>
> To find the import conditions for bringing cheesecakes, dairy puddings or vanilla slices into Australia, you may consult Biosecurity Import Conditions system (BICON) at https://bicon.agriculture.gov.au/BiconWeb4.0. This
>   database lists the Quarantine conditions under which various
>   commodities may be brought into Australia. Using the ICON search
>   facility, enter ‘Dairy’ into the ‘Commodity’ field, insert the country
>   of manufacture in the ‘From country’ field and leave ‘All End Uses’ in
>   the ‘For end-use’ field. Then, click “search” and the database will
>   return the results. If an AQIS Import Permit is required, or if any
>   other specific conditions apply, ICON will specify this.
>
> The information available on ICON is the same information that AQIS’s clearing officers use when inspecting and clearing goods
>   arriving into the country. I recommend that you refer to this database
>   regularly to keep up to date with any import condition changes by
>   AQIS.
>
> Confectionery (excluding Indian milk-based desserts and sweets) is permitted into Australia providing the items are free of contaminants
>   such as live insects. Confectionery includes toffees, chocolate,
>   fudge, boiled sweets, peppermints, marshmallows, liquorice, etc. It
>   does not include liquid dairy desserts, spreads or drinks.
>
> Once passengers arrive in Australia, they are required to complete an Incoming Passenger Card (IPC). On the IPC, they must declare all
>   items of food, animal or plant origin as well as any other articles
>   that are covered on the card (e.g. medicines, wooden articles) – these
>   items are only examples illustrating the types of items that must be
>   declared under each category. All items of food, animal or plant
>   origin must be declared on the IPC for the purpose of inspection by an
>   Australian Quarantine Inspector.
>
> After passengers have collected their luggage, they will be directed to a Quarantine Officer who will inspect any declared items
>   and inspect and/or x-ray any remaining luggage before they depart the
>   international arrivals area.
>
> For further information on what goods can or cannot be brought into Australia, you may visit our website at www.daff.gov.au/aqis or
>   our Import Conditions database (ICON) at www.aqis.gov.au/icon. This
>   database lists the Quarantine conditions under which various
>   commodities may be brought into Australia. Using the ICON search
>   facility, enter the item into the ‘Commodity’ field, insert the
>   country of manufacture or origin in the ‘From country’ field and leave
>   ‘All End Uses’ in the ‘For end-use’ field. Then, click “search” and
>   the database will return the results. If an AQIS Import Permit is
>   required, or if any other specific conditions apply, ICON will specify
>   this.
>
> The information available on ICON is the same information that AQIS’s clearing officers use when inspecting and clearing goods
>   arriving into the country. I recommend that you refer to this database
>   regularly to keep up to date with any import condition changes by
>   AQIS.

In addition, just last month I brought boxed chocolates and shortbread from NZ to Australia, and declared them, and had zero problems.

Comment: As of the latest Incoming Passenger Form (dated 11/12), the question regarding "Food" no longer exists, and now only specific types of food that are explicitly listed on the form need to be declared.

Comment: @MarkMayo I updated the link to the Biosecurity Import Conditions system (BICON) although I recognize that it is not how it appeared in the original content, nor in the remainer of the info. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Giorgio not that I can really think of.  The main info is there at least.

Answer (score 8):

Australia has recently changed the wording on the Incoming Passenger Card, and no longer even ask if you are carrying "Food" as they used to - but instead of certain types of listed food.

The questions now ask if you are bringing in :

6 - Meat, poultry, fish, seafood, eggs, dairy, fruit, vegetables?

7 - Grains, seeds, bulbs, straw, nuts, plants, parts of plants, traditional
medicines or herbs, wooden articles?

8 - Animals, parts of animals, animal products including equipment, pet food,
eggs, biologicals, specimens, birds, fish, insects, shells, bee products?

Previously question 6 included the word "Food", but as of last month this reference is gone.

The question then becomes is chocolate "dairy" as most chocolate contains dairy products - but in general I think the answer to that would be no.

Certainly the immigrations officer I dealt with last week told me that the chocolates I was bringing in did NOT need to be declared - where previously they would have had to be declared, but would have been let through without any issues.

You can find a copy of the latest Incoming Passenger Form [here](http://www.immi.gov.au/managing-australias-borders/border-security/travel/passenger-cards/_pdf/english-ipc-sample.pdf).

Comment: Any chocolate including dairy, is a dairy product, and should probably be declared just to be safe. Australia is thorough about their customs, but they also have a lot of employees and the line is usually quite fast.