# Should I declare chocolate as "food" when entering the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, local-customs

It is being customary we bring a few authentic Russian chocolate bars/sweets to the US but we are always struggling whether we should check that "food" checkbox in the "Customs Declaration" form?

It is under the following entry in the form (yeah, together with insects, right):

> I am (We are) bringing:
>
> fruits, vegetables, plants, seeds, food, insects

I've been always checking it but that just gets us into more lines and triggers extra questions after getting to the baggage check.

Comment: Related question, same foodstuff, different country, slightly different question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10930/can-i-take-chocolate-to-australia

Comment: As a side note, do not put your chocolate inside a suitcase that has soap, shampoo, or perfume. I found out the hard way. I would double bag it.

Comment: You could squeeze in some information on the form and say "chocolate" next to the Yes [X]

Comment: @ScotParker Ew!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Yes, according to US CBP officers, you should declare it as food. I bring chocolate every time I fly from Europe.

Generally what happens next is they ask what exactly you are bringing, you say "chocolate" and they let you go.

As a general rule, if you are not sure whether something needs to be declared or not, declare it. There are no penalties for declaring something which doesn't need to be declared.

Comment: This is my experience as well. I sometimes volunteer that it’s prepackaged chocolate when I hand in the paperwork at customs, and they usually wave me through.

Comment: If you say anything reasonable (e.g. "canned fish", "chocolate", "nuts", etc.) the CBP people will hardly raise their eyebrows.

Comment: Last time I cautiously declared something that ended up not being declare-worthy, after some paperwork shuffling the officers got rather impatient and rude with me for seemingly wasting their time, making me feel less than excellent. However, this is better than the alternative, the outcome if you're caught not declaring something that you should!

Comment: Less than excellent?  @Lightness no!

Comment: @xuq01 the magic word is "meat" or "sausage". Most reasonable packaged foods , sweets, and condiments are allowed in and will get a pass, but in a mirror scenario, practically all meats even commercially packaged and vacuum packed are banned unless specifically certified for import (rare specialty tourist shops) and will  practically guarantee an inspection when declared.

Comment: @crasic You are not supposed to bring any meat anyways (except for canned meat), so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @crasic:  Fresh produce (fruits & vegetables) will usually need to be inspected as well.  In both cases, the main concern is pathogens/pests that could adversely affect US agriculture.

Comment: Well, even "chocolate" in the form of Kinder eggs could be verboten (the real kind, not the imitation we have).

Comment: @crasic: Why is that?

Comment: Many agricultural products, including meat, vegetables, and fruits, are subject to inspection at many borders (not just the US) to prevent the spread of animal and plant diseases and pests from one nation's farms to to another's. This is a long-standing practice. Consider fruit flies and bovine spongiform encephalopathy ("mad cow disease") and you'll see the motivation.

Comment: I think those forms are generally interested in unprocessed/raw foods, things that are most likely to carry disease or pests, but there are other illegal foods that might be prepared (horse jerky? beluga caviar), so it's easiest to just say "food" on a form.

Comment: Just to add to these comments, one time my wife (American) said we don't need to bother filling out the customs form, even though we had chocolate gifts. The officer just looked at us and said "You *really* don't have anything? Not even chocolate?". Luckily he didn't really grill us and allowed us to just fill the form in, seemingly, correctly this time. Now we always fill it out, regardless if the "food" is trivial (e.g. small bar of chocolate)

Comment: Update to my above comment; just went through customs at IAH, checked yes because I had chocolate. Officer asked what I was declaring, I said chocolate, he waved me through. He confirmed I answered correctly.

Answer (score 44):

a) Chocolate, being a thing eaten by humans, is indeed "food."

b) If you say you're not carrying food, and your baggage is searched by Customs and the chocolate discovered, then they have you for lying on your Customs forms. That would be uncomfortable, possibly expensive, and could result in entry to the US being delayed or denied.

Comment: That's an important point that many people do not seem to know. If you do not declare something which you should have declared, you may be fined (or worse), sometimes even if the item is allowed! But if you declare it, then you won't be fined (or worse) even if the item is not allowed to enter the country. (Of course this doesn't include illegal things like weapons or drugs...) You might still have to pay tax or duty sometimes though.

Comment: Presumably you don't have to pay duty if it's not allowed in but confiscated and destroyed instead. @MichaelHampton

Comment: By that criterion, dogs should be declared as food, too?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni not if they're alive.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: looking at US customs declaration form 6059b, both meats and animals are listed under 11(b) anyway. (I don't suppose the usual human microbiome will count as animals, though.)

Comment: If they really hate you, lying to CBP violates 18 USC 1001, which is a *felony*.  So definitely don't lie.

Comment: @AndrewLeach No, you don't have to pay duty on items that aren't allowed in.

Comment: +1 And you might want to simply say 'eaten' as there are travellers bringing food for pets (with or without those pets).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Probably not, given that (unless you happen to be carrying parasitic worms or something) those are bacteria, archaea, and protists, not animals.

Comment: @Kevin: If you mistakenly failed to declare it because you didn't realise it counted as something needing to be declared, then you wouldn't be _willfully_ lying to CBP, and that particular charge would be inapplicable.  It's impossible to be guilty of a crime you didn't willfully commit.

Comment: @Sean: Yes, that's what the law *says.*  But it's ultimately a matter of what a judge or jury is willing to believe.  I doubt they'd actually charge you for one chocolate bar.  But if you have a box of 'em, "I didn't know chocolate was food" is going to come off as a pretty lame excuse.

Comment: @Kevin "I didn't know chocolate was food" is going to come off pretty lame in any event.

Comment: @Sean There are many examples of crimes where you can be guilty without having intended to commit the crime — drunk driving, for example. It’s called strict liability.

Comment: @MikeScott: How, pray tell, would one unintentionally drive drunk (well, unless someone bodily picked them up, strapped them into the driver's seat, and weighed down the accelerator pedal)?

Comment: @Sean By having 81 micrograms of alcohol per 100ml of blood when you thought you only had 79 and were therefore legal to drive (or whatever your jurisdiction’s limit is).

Comment: @MikeScott: You would still be driving after intentionally drinking.  Not seeing how this is an example of lack of intention.

Comment: @Sean Driving after intentionally drinking is not a crime and you can’t be prosecuted for it. The crime is driving above a specific number for your blood alcohol, and no one intends to do that, because they don’t know what their number is.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, you then get a choice to pay the duty or have it destroyed. Some countries might bill you for the destruction, maybe. Never had to deal with that situation myself but I can see governments seeing dollar signs and creating fees like that.

Comment: @Sean another way is taking certain medication, like cough syrup, that's alcohol based. This can leave enough alcohol residue in your breath for a while to trigger a breath test (though a subsequent blood test would almost certainly clear you).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, always declare all food. Your honesty will be much appreciated by CBP. 
I have always been treated profesionally, with courtesy, even friendly. I always itemize my food on the Customs form, emphasizing meat products. It's foolish to hide any, they (used to) have these Beagle dogs that will rat you out by sitting down and giving you that cute look.

In 2010 I hoped to bring the ingredients for split pea soup, including smoked sausage. Meat per se was not forbidden, it depended on the diseases of the period, and this was a foot-and-mouth season. They made me translate all the ingredients lists, and as soon as I reached "beef collagen" the article was confiscated. So I skipped right to the "beef" parts and I lost over half my food stuff. I received no penalty, of course, but my host who loves the soup was less happy.

Comment: Yeah. The beagle's official denomination is [Agriculgure Canine](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/protecting-agriculture/agriculture-canine). And they are as cute as their smell is **a**cute.

Comment: That's a sad story!  I would be very sad to miss out on a traditional soup like that!

Answer (score 3):

You need to answer all questions honestly, so if the question is about whether you are carrying food, you need to answer yes, since chocolate is food.

If the question is confusing and you don't know whether to declare it or not, you should always declare it, since there is zero penalty (except for some of your time) for declaring something you didn't need to, but fairly severe penalties (even if the item found is non-harmful or is confiscated) if you don't declare something you should have.